# If $T^m$ is a contraction, has $T$ got a fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and complete and $T: X\to X$ a mapping such that $T^m$ is a contraction. Show that $T$ has a unique fixed point.

It is clear that $T^m$ has a unique fixed point (Banach theorem) but, how can you use it to prove the existence of a fixed point of $T$?

Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, I looked up before writing and I did not find it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $T^mx_0=x_0$, $T^m(Tx_0)=T(T^mx_0)=Tx_0$, so $Tx_0$ is fixed by $T^m$. By unicity, it must be $x_0$.

Comment: I thought it must be easy but not as easy. Now I feel a little bit upset haha Many thanks!